# Google AdMob error on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, ads

I'm using adMob sdk 4.3.1 for android and am using xml to create the layout as explained [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html) using Eclipse IDE. The problem is that eclipse doesn't recognize the `com.google.ads.AdView` tag and gives the error **error: error parsing XML: unbound prefix**. How do I fix this?

**EDIT**-Here's the code for the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,e78b974e6ab65648b52951e69edcb571"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you used the code from the link exactly?

Comment: The only difference in my implementation is that I'm not adding this field in main.xml but in a layout being used in the app.

Answer (score 8):

Just add  `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" to the layout!`

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here, you'll have to post your xml (obviously):

You're missing `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` or you've spelt something wrong.

Comment: Nah...it's there...I think it is an issue with importing the library

Comment: If you haven't fixed this yet, post xml in the question?

Comment: How about the other prefix?  Do you have `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` in your xml?

Comment: Sorry, I had found the problem, I didn't provide the adMob ID instead of `MY_AD_UNIT_ID`. I didn't think anyone would make that mistake so didn't update!